# Training a classifier to predict unknown classes

Tags: classification

I am building a classifier where I have data from two known classes, but I want to capture any new or "unknown" classes as well in my prediction. However, in my case, I do not have any examples of the unknown classes as the data is a multidimensional time-series coming out of sensors, and it's difficult to create such unknown data.

What is the best way to handle such cases?

Comment: If you formulate "borders" or "radiuses" of the classes in some sense the idea becomes straightforward. This is also the question of "detect outliers/noise" field.

Comment: @ttnphns: Can you give any example or technique to formulate such radiuses?